# Rational arithmetic, how to represent fractional numbers?

Tags: c#, math

Is there any standard C# type or library for exact rational arithmetic, like division?

Decimal isn't what I need:

```
1m/3m + 1m/3m + 1m/3m != 1
```

I am thinking about something which stores two decimals, numerator and denominator, and performs multiplications and divisions exactly. Which can simplify fractions when needed and do explicit conversion to double or decimal.

Comment: Check [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11971/Fractions-in-C) out, it might help you implement it yourself at least.

Comment: I implemented this once using System.Numerics.BigInteger and it wasn't a big deal. Problem is that such an approach can be very very slow since every multiplication or division duplicates the number of digits in the nominator or denominator.

Comment: There is such a type in Microsoft.SolverFoundation.Common, but I prefer not to rely on it (no one has that DLL). It's easy to roll your own anyway.

Comment: Besides the link commented by @Tobberoth, you can also check [this one](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/88980/Rational-Numbers-NET-4-0-Version-Rational-Computin).

Comment: simplifying fractions when needed (prime factorization) is crucial

Comment: @user2622016 just divide by the GCD. Prime factorization is massive overkill.

Comment: @user2622016 yes, you should DIY.

Comment: @harold you're right, one should use Euclid's algorithm for simplifying a quotient

Comment: There's the [BigRationalLibrary](https://www.nuget.org/packages/BigRationalLibrary/) on NuGet.