# Implementation of decimal in C#. Is it possible to amend it to support repeating decimals?

Tags: c#, math

There is this problem with C# decimal type:

```
Console.WriteLine( 1m/3 + 1m/3 == 2m/3 );

False
```

It can represent numbers exactly only when dividing by 2 or 5, otherwise result could be [repeating decimal number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Repeating_decimal).

As mentioned on Stack Overflow before ([C# Rational arithmetic](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19855592/2622016)), implementing something which stores two decimals, numerator and denominator, and performs multiplications and divisions exactly is quite possible. It can simplify fractions when needed using Euclid's algorithm. Some explicit conversion to double or decimal should also be implemented.

There are some rational quotients implementations presented [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11971/Fractions-in-C) and [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/88980/Rational-Numbers-NET-4-0-Version-Rational-Computin). There is also a [Microsoft Solver Foundation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.solverfoundation.common%28v=vs.93%29.aspx) structure [Rational](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.solverfoundation.common.rational%28v=vs.93%29.aspx).

How `decimal` in C# is implemented and is it possible to copy this implementation and modify it to handle *repeating* `decimal`s ?

There are some trials related to repeating decimals presented in SO answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14481780/2622016) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14534664/2622016)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`decimal` is implemented as a significand, sign and exponent, basically - a floating point number, where the "point" is a decimal point instead of a binary point (as per `float` and `double`). See my [article on the topic](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Decimal.aspx) for more details. (Note that unlike `float` and `double`, `decimal` isn't normalized - so it will retain trailing insignificant zeroes, for example.)

If you wanted to create your own `RationalNumber` type you could do so, but you wouldn't want to start with the source code to `decimal` - and you wouldn't be able to change the meaning of `decimal` to mean your type, either.